# Unable to store data in Array variables in Java

Tags: java

Customer file having three rows of data in a column,

```
101
102
103
```

Trying to store in three Arrays like

```
cust[0]=101
cust[1]=102
cust[2]=103
```

My code:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Customer.txt"));
String[] Default = reader.readLine();
int i = 0,c = 0;
while (( Default = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
    c = ++i;
}
for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j) { 
    System.out.println("Element at index " + j +": " + Default[j]);
}
```

Giving an error like

```
error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to String[]
```

Comment: `reader.readLine()` returns `String`. You are trying to assign it to `String[]`. Basic programming, mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default variable is of wrong type , readLine function returns String , and not array of String. Check this link for more clarification-https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

You can create another variable of type String[] and add values to it , something like ->

```
  String Default;
        int i = 0;
        String [] resultArray = new String[10];
        while ((Default = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            resultArray[i] = Default;
            i++;

        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            System.out.println("Element at index " + j + ": " + resultArray[j]);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working. But it is printing the last two rows only.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

```
String BufferedReader::readLine() throws IOException {
```

wrong type of Default variable. It should be `String`